# How to check if hardware accelarated AES is supported in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, hardware-acceleration, aes-ni

I am developing e project where I am doing AES encryption with CBC mode.

But I need to know does java AES implementation use Hardware Acceleration (AES-NI CPU instruction set).

As far as I know that form lollipop hardware accelerated disk encryption is possible. Is there any way to check whether my phone support it or not?

Comment: AES-NI is an extension of the x86 instruction set, i.e. it's supported by all the latest Intel and AMD processors. Phones normally run on ARM based processors. Those processors may also feature accelerated AES instructions, but those are not AES-NI.

Comment: I am doing this in google nexus 5. Is there any way to test whether it support accelerated AES

Comment: Ask on an android forum, or find out the processor and try and find out yourself. I don't think you'll find that kind of detail on the device itself.

Comment: thanks. I already asked on forum.

Comment: It worth giving us a link to follow :)

Comment: A related question which contains some background info: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/186664/20532